# Woocommerce - remove the added to cart animated popup panel

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have my store setup so that when adding a product to the basket the user gets taken to the cart page.

An animated panel slides in from the right hand side on this page with the message "x has been added to your basket".

I can not find anywhere this can be edited/turned off/set to appear for a shorter time etc. I assume this is a Woocommerce feature and not my theme, but theres not much documentation about it either. It seems you have it without any choice, and it seems to be interfering with the checkout process since the proceed to checkout button appears under this panel

Where do I look/what can I do to remove this entirely? I preferred it when you used to get a normal line of text I think with a little check mark next to it that stayed top of page to notifiy whats just happened.

Thanks
Steve

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can have a try with this function to add to your functions.php file of your theme:

```
add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message', 'remove_add_to_cart_message' );

function remove_add_to_cart_message() {
    return;
}
```